# How can I merge the text with the same column names using the Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use the Excel the formula, which merge the values if the column name the same, for example:

```
ColumnHi                    ColumnHi            ColumnHi       ColumnOa
a                                                               b
a                           b
a                           b                   c               yy
```

Desired Result:

```
ColumnHi                    ColumnOa
a                           b
a,b
a,b,c                       yy
```

There may be a different number of identical columns.

I have already tried that formula, which merge the values in the columns:

```
=A1 & "," & B1
```

But it works manually for a specific case and does not take into game the same column names

Comment: Is the column name keep on changing (like a link or formula).. ?

Comment: No, the column name is not a link or formula

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7). For example, create a new column and paste :

```
=CONCAT(IF($A$1:$D$1=F$1,IF(A2:D2<>0,A2:D2,""),""))
```

Assuming you table is in the range "A1:D4", "F1" contains the name of the column you want to merge, and F2 contains this formula :

[image]

As this is in array formula, don't forget to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after entering the formula.

Comment: Thank you, but this formula is not working. It shows: #NAME?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you running ? Do you have the "Concat" function available ?

Comment: Excel 2016. Now I am using CONCATENATE() and it returns only first value: ColumnHi
a
a
a

Comment: This is strange : CONCAT() should be available for your version according to the documentation : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/concat-function-9b1a9a3f-94ff-41af-9736-694cbd6b4ca2
Are you using Excel in a particular locale ?
Do you have the formula TEXTJOIN() available ?

Comment: Note: This feature is available on Windows or Mac if you have Office 2019. I have Office 2016. No, there is no TEXTJOIN() function.

Comment: Have you tried something like '=IF(A$1=F$1,A2,"")&IF(B$1=F$1,B2,"")&IF(C$1=F$1,C2,"")&IF(D$1=F$1,D2,"")'. It's a bit tedious especially if you have numerous columns, but it can do the job. Except for that, I cannot figure out other solution for these older versions of Excel